# Search while typing keyword on a particular column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I am trying to implement a functionality using the gridview.keydown event in WPF using c# with following code

```
string searchText = e.Key.ToString();

PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MarketWatchOM).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchPreferanceMarketWatch) && property.Name.ToUpper().Equals(SearchPreferanceMarketWatch.ToUpper()))
    {
        var item = this.MktWatchGrid.Items.Cast<MarketWatchOM>().Any(selectedRow =>
    selectedRow.CustomSymbol.StartsWith(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        if (item == null)
            return;

        this.MktWatchGrid.CurrentItem = item;
        this.MktWatchGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
        break;
    }
}
```

Here what I am able to catch is a single key stroke. Can you suggest any way to capture a complete 'word' and then the method will search for that complete word in the column.

How can I alter my code to get the desired word?

Comment: Have you tried the Leave event on the Textbox? When the textbox loses focus, you can try and search with the text in the TextBox

Comment: Hi, there will be no text box. User will have to simply type over readonly grid and requirement is to set focus to that particular row which satisfy the user input.

Comment: Apologies. For some reason I thought I read TextBox somehwere, must be my tired mind.

Comment: :) thanks for the efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to save each keystroke to a field somewhere, until you reach something that indicates the end of the word. Outside of your method, have a private field:

```
private string _searchText = "";
```

Then change the first line of your code to:

```
_searchText += e.Key.ToString();
```

Finally, change all references to `searchText` to `_searchText`.

This will keep track of all key presses.

You may also need to include a timer, and after 2-3 seconds of no typing, 'forget' what the user has already typed. This is similar to the way that file/list searching works in other applications.

Comment: For now i just have to reach/set focus to a particular row with that record. It's just an open ended search keyword

Comment: Ok, I will try that , but being a very new to coding  can you also give a pseudo code as how can i maintain this through timer?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pete's answer here are some instructions about using timer:

Use DispatcherTimer. Create a single instance of timer, set interval for 3 seconds and subscribe to it's TickEvent. Every time key is pressed start/restart timer. In TickEvent handler stop timer and clear your searchtextstring. DispatcherTimer tutorial wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer

Comment: Yes, I did the same .But this is resulting into a new problem. :(
"e.Key.ToString()"  giving me 'D1' as string when pressing 1 from keyyboard or Numpad1 when doing the same from NumPad. Any idea which value or property should i use for correct value?